# All cyrillic symbols are wrongly encoded in network inspector in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1251

All cyrillic symbols which I get in json body are encoded in the folliwing way inside network inspector:

```
{
      "РњР°РіР°Р·РёРЅ": "dd29a406-1484-11ed-bb9a-0050569d338f",
      "Р�СЃС‚РѕСЂРёСЏ": "d07df264-d546-4292-a8df-3d8c5253aed2",
      "РџРѕСЂСЏРґРѕРє": 965,
      "Р�СЃС‚РѕСЂРёСЏРџСЂРѕСЃРјРѕС‚СЂРµРЅР°": false,
      "РЈР Р›РџСЂРµРІСЊСЋ": "https://i.ibb.co/WGhVNhv/image.jpg",
      "Р�РјСЏР�СЃС‚РѕСЂРёРё": "Telegram Рё Р’РєРѕРЅС‚Р°РєС‚Рµ_РЅРѕРІС‹Р№ С„РѕСЂРјР°С‚",
      "Р”Р°С‚Р°РћРєРѕРЅС‡Р°РЅРёСЏ": "2022-12-31T00:00:00"
    }
```

I managed to find out that this hieroglyphs appear when we encode UTF-8 with the help of Windows-1251. I tried to change the encoding inside android studio, but did not get the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: `I tried to change the encoding inside android studio` ? I would think you would do that with code for your Android app when you get the json body. And why network inspector? Why not in your app at receiving the json? Also show the cyrillic text.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Магазин'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1251')` returns `'РњР°РіР°Р·РёРЅ'` and vice versa: `"РњР°РіР°Р·РёРЅ".encode( 'cp1251').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'Магазин'` (the 1st line of your `json`) or `'Р”Р°С‚Р°РћРєРѕРЅС‡Р°РЅРёСЏ'.encode( 'cp1251').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'ДатаОкончания'` (the last `json` line).